# call two different methods based on emissions of two observables

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

currently, I have a cabinet with some drawers, each drawer has some items that users can manipulate. Whenever the user switches to a different drawer an observable `(D)` fires. As soon as the user swithces to a drawer, another observable (I) fires with an array of Items available in that drawer.
My desired behaviour is for the follwoing stream:

```
Drawer(D): --D----------------------------D--...
Items(I): -------I----I-----I-----I-----I----I--..
```

for an emission `(D)` and first following emission `(I)` => call a function (`setCurrentDrawerItems()`)

for all following emissions of `(I)` that are not interrupted by an emission `(D)` =>
call the function (`userPickedItemFromDrawer()`)

how can I achieve this using rxjs operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to tag your observable emissions to cleanly separate the two in the merged stream. For example, shoving them into an object with the label `t`. Then you can just query that label to know what to do next.

Something like this might work:

```ts
merge(

  drawer$.pipe(map(v => ({ t: 'D', v }))),
  items$.pipe(map(v => ({ t: 'I', v })))

).pipe(

  startWith({ t: 'I', v: null }), 
  pairwise()

).subscribe(([prev, curr]) => {

  if (curr.t == 'D' || (curr.t == 'I' && prev.t == 'D')) {
    setCurrentDrawerItems(curr.v);
  } else {
    userPickedItemFromDrawer(curr.v);
  }
  
});
```